# Same Project(s) - Different Branches - Eclipse with CVS

Tags: java, eclipse, repository, branch, cvs

I have two CVS branches that are named after the release schedule like Apr_15, Jun_15. Both are actually same project with same names, but branched out separately as above for different release schedule and for different feature set.

Is it possible to work with both of them at the same time in eclipse, without switching back and forth (i.e. using `Replace With -> Another Branch or Version` option in eclipse)? If not possible, what is the alternative approach?

I read [Eclipse vs. CVS: Same Modules, Multiple Branches/Tags](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6356860/668650). Didn't help.

PS: Both have same name.

Comment: The suggestion in the answer you linked (to check out multiple branches into projects with different names) has always worked for me.  Can you be more specific about how that solution doesn't do what you need?

Comment: I would say, its confusing. And I do not have any dependency. In my case, its basically same project branched out twice with same project name. I would like to use both of them in eclipse.